# how to make a dropdown submenu in ionic 6 with angular

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, ionic6

How can I turn Ionic's basic side menu into a side menu with dropdown submenus?

```
 //html
 <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index">
            <ion-item routerDirection="root" [routerLink]="[p.url]" lines="none" detail="false" routerLinkActive="selected">
              <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" slot="start" [ios]="p.icon + '-outline'" [md]="p.icon + '-sharp'"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
              
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
```

```
js
export class AppComponent {
  public open=0;
  public appPages = [
    { title: 'Inbox', url: '/folder/inbox', icon: 'mail' },
    { title: 'Outbox', url: '/folder/outbox', icon: 'paper-plane' },
    { title: 'Favorites', url: '/folder/favorites', icon: 'heart' },
    { title: 'Archived', url: '/folder/archived', icon: 'archive' },
    { title: 'Trash', url: '/folder/trash', icon: 'trash' },
    { title: 'Spam', url: '/folder/spam', icon: 'warning',      
    subPages: [
      { title: 'subtest1', url: '' },
      { title: 'subtest2', url: '' },
      { title: 'subtest3', url: '' },
      { title: 'subtest4', url: '' },
      { title: 'subtest5', url: '' },
      { title: 'subtest6', url: '' },
      { title: 'subtest7', url: '' },
      { title: 'subtest8', url: '' }
      ] 
    },
  ];
  public labels = ['Family', 'Friends', 'Notes', 'Work', 'Travel', 'Reminders'];
  constructor() {}
}
```

<ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index">
<ion-item routerDirection="root" [routerLink]="[p.url]" lines="none" detail="false" routerLinkActive="selected">
<ion-icon aria-hidden="true" slot="start" [ios]="p.icon + '-outline'" [md]="p.icon + '-sharp'">
{{ p.title }}



Submenu




Item 1
Item 2
Item 3